# GrovePi / Cannot find module 'i2c-bus'

Tags: raspberry-pi3, iot, raspbian, node-red, grovepi+

I would like to use Node-Red on my RaspberryPi B 3+ with GrovePi, but I get the same error message every time again and again.

`[node-red-contrib-grovepi/grovepi] Error: Cannot find module 'i2c-bus'`

i2c is enabled in the `raspi-config` and I have everything installed that I've read on Node-Red/RPI Configuration.

Thanks to all!

Comment: How did you install the Node-RED nodes? Also were there any errors when you did. I would suggest reinstalling the `node-red-contrib-grovepi` node.

Comment: If you don't update the question with the information I've asked for there is little we can do to help you

Comment: @hardillb I'm sorry for the late answer. First I installed the nodes through npm on the console, that didn't solved the problem. So I removed them and installed them directly from localhost deploy , by going to "Manage Palette" from the menu and I searched for GrovePi and installed the 3 nodes that were available. The `node-red-grovepi-nodes` worked but the `node-red-contrib-grovepi` doesn't, and that is the one I need. It says [object Object] and "board-config"